# how to run a python program in linux crontab?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, cron

I have added the following line in contab

```
 1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/prkumar/Desktop/python/sample.py
```

my **sample.py** file

```
  text_file = open("sample.log", "a")
  text_file.write("Hi...")
  text_file.write("\n")
  text_file.close()
```

If I run the python program in terminal it's working fine and also append the text in sample.log file. But there is no response if add the program in crontab.

Thanks

Comment: maybe with python shebang as first line? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change python instead of /usr/bin/python, Change your code as follows.

```
1 * * * * python /home/prkumar/Desktop/python/sample.py >> /home/prkumar/Desktop/python/output.log
```

Answer (score 6):

You need a correction :

`* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/prkumar/Desktop/python/sample.py`

to run it every minute.

Your cron statement :
`1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/prkumar/Desktop/python/sample.py`

would run it only at first minute of every hour eg 09:01, 10:01...etc. Hence, you will have to wait 1 hour to see the result.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

yes. I am running the command for every minute.

Comment: https://github.com/homer6/frequent-cron if you want to run more frequently than once a minute...

Comment: @sasi Why was the other answer voted as correct answer ? Was that the actual problem you were facing instead of this ?

Comment: you should use */1 * * * *  to run every minute,
1 * * * *  runs first minute of every hour..